# Incorect syntax near with nullable datetime parameter

Tags: c#

I have some query which has VerifiedDate which is DateTime. This could be either with value or null.
I added parameter as shown below. Nevertheless when trying to add to my query where clause i got exception.

```
Parameters.Add(Context.CreateParameter("@VerifiedDate", 30, (object) Car.VerifiedDate ?? DBNull.Value, DbType.DateTime));

queryWhereClause = " AND VerifiedDate=@VerifiedDate";
```

Exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '='.'
```

Comment: i believe the sqlexception has an sql component so you can see the outcome sql, could you post that? (or its should be somewhere else)

Comment: SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE VerifiedDate=@VerifiedDate

Comment: @sommmen  sorry that was my mistake in WHERE, nevertheless instead of getting two rows i get 0, i assume its because it should be IS NULL in query and not = but how to say when there is a value put = and when dbnull IS NULL into query? Because now i assume when my value is NULL it puts like: VerifiedDate=NULL

Comment: Well i mostly work with EF so i've only done this a couple of times, can't you just not add queryWhereClause string to the rest of the query if Car.VerifiedData is null in code?

Comment: @Arie: Do you mean like this?: `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE VerifiedDate= ISNULL(@VerifiedDate, VerifiedDate)` Or how do you want to use the parameter?

Comment: @mm8 if value is null then in sql there should be added WHERE VerifiedDate IS NULL but if some value  WHERE VerifiedDate=@VerifiedDate  ,i think i should do like this: queryWhereClause = Car.VerifiedDate == null ? "  VerifiedDate IS NULL" : "VerifiedDate=@VerifiedDate";

Comment: it works but now it doesn;t make sense even declaring dbnull as in queryWhereClause  i already defining what should be puted

Comment: Then it's `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE (@VerifiedDate IS NULL AND VerifiedDate IS NULL) OR
VerifiedDate = @VerifiedDate` then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, SQL Server (in ANSI compliant mode) requires different syntax for null matching. Frankly, in your case I would just do:

```cs
if (Car.VerifiedDate.HasValue)
{
    Parameters.Add(Context.CreateParameter("@VerifiedDate", 30, Car.VerifiedDate.Value, DbType.DateTime));
    queryWhereClause = " AND VerifiedDate=@VerifiedDate";
}
else
{
    queryWhereClause = " AND VerifiedDate IS NULL";
}
```

However, you can also do things like:

```sql
AND (VerifiedDate=@VerifiedDate OR (VerifiedDate IS NULL AND @VerifiedDate IS NULL))
```

The server will usually work better with the first approach, since it is fewer conditions and branches - and it can make the most effective use if an index if one exists.

Comment: this is more like what i've written above in comment :) this should work. The first approach